# Swampdragon - Issues when deploying in webfaction

Tags: websocket, connection, webfaction, swampdragon

I have installed swampdragon in webfaction. According to webfaction documentation (https://docs.webfaction.com/software/custom.html?highlight=custom#creating-a-custom-application) to use port I have to create a custom application.

1. created custom app
2. added domain_name for the custom app
3. DRAGON_URL = 'http://sock.domain_name.com:28083'
4. started the server

And still "GET http://sock.domain_name.com:28083/settings.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error is occuring.

In local it is working fine. I dnt know how to work in production environment. Please help to resolve this issue .. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this with SwampDragon, but have just set up a  Python/CherryPy/websockets test on WebFaction. The following may be useful.

As far as I can tell, WebFaction reroutes traffic from the standard (HTTP and websocket) ports to the custom app's port. So don't put the port number number in the URLs (for settings.js, for the ws:// address in the Javascript, etc). Only put it in the websocket configuration - so the application knows which port to listen on